# What are ALL the methods to pass variables into a class?

Tags: php, class, variables

I have more than 15 variables in my main code and need to pass all of them into a class. I don't want to pass all of them while calling the methods TWO and THREE (method injection) because I have to repeat lots code. On the other hand, I can't pass them using construct injection because I have to repeat all the variables while calling a method. What are ALL the different methods to pass variables into a class?
Note that my variables are keep changing inside a for loop.

Main code:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($updateArray["result"]) - 1; $x++) {
    $process = new ONE();
    $type = $updateArray["result"][$x]["message"];
    $aa = $updateArray["result"][$x]["update_id"];

        if (array_key_exists("set_to", $type)) {
            $bb = $updateArray["result"][$x]["text"];
            $cc = $updateArray["result"][$x]["width"];
                $action = $process->TWO($aa, $bb, $cc);
        }
        elseif (array_key_exists("delete_from", $type)) {
            $cc = $updateArray["result"][$x]["width"];
            $dd = $updateArray["result"][$x]["file_size"];
                $action = $process->THREE($aa, $cc, $dd);
        }   
        else {
            //do something else
        }
}
```

Class ONE:

```
class ONE{
    public $aa, $bb, $cc, $dd;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->aa = $aa;
}
    public function TWO($aa, $bb, $cc) {
        $this->bb = $bb;
        $this->cc = $cc;
        // need to repeat lots of code like this: $this->xxx = $xxx
        //use these variables: (aa, bb, cc) 

}
    public function THREE($aa, $cc, $dd) {
        $this->bb = $cc;
        $this->cc = $dd;
        // need to repeat lots of code like this: $this->xxx = $xxx
        //use these variables: (aa, cc, dd)     
}
}
```

Comment: What about creating getters and setters in a class per each variable? Also your architecture looks a bit rubbish if you require that much variable in single class..

Comment: Your functions set the same variables. Why not just have setters for those vars directly? Like setA, setB,setC. This way you wont need to repeat your methods.

Comment: So, you want to set a variable to X value, but you don't want to use `$variable = X;`? Interesting...

Comment: @FirstOne I'll use them but I don't want to repeat common variables among different methods.

Comment: @divix : How? I couldn't understand. Do you have any suggestion regarding architecture?

Comment: @MuhammedM: Different methods have both common and uncommon variables and each of them are doing different computation.

Comment: @R.Toward It looks like your methods are doing too much work and also have a look at Facade, Strategy and Decorator Design Patterns..